# Why tinyMCE is not starting after load by createElement?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, createelement

I'm trying to start tinyMCE after loading the library by `createElement` but it doesn't work!

Maybe I am forgetting something, I don't know...

Basically the function is:

```
scriptLoad = false;    

function tinyInit() {
    if (!scriptLoad) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = '/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js';
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.body.appendChild(s);
        scriptLoad = true;
    }

    // wait until load
    if (typeof tinyMCE == 'undefined') {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            tinyInit();
        }, 120);
    }
    else {
        // alright! bring it to me
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: 'textareas',
            theme: 'simple'
        });
    }
}
```

I've tested with Firebug and the library exists. Changing the value of `tinyMCE.baseURL` does not work because it has the right value.

I apreciate any help!

Thanks

---

Resolved!

I was looking at the source code and saw that init creates two default properties: theme and language. I don't know why they are not extending our settings when the library is loaded by `createElement` or AJAX. So the solution is set these two properties on init:

```
scriptLoad = false;    

function tinyInit() {
    if (!scriptLoad) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = '/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js';
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.body.appendChild(s);
        scriptLoad = true;
    }

    // wait until load
    if (typeof tinyMCE == 'undefined') {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            tinyInit();
        }, 120);
    }
    else {
        // alright! bring it to me
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: 'textareas',
            theme: 'simple',
            language: 'en'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `tinyInit` the first time? `this.src` will refer to `window.src`, is this what you want? You are also never setting `scriptLoad` to `true`.

Comment: sorry for mistake, the right value for this.src is the path of tinyMCE and i forget scriptLoad. This code is an abstract of the code i'm using

Answer (score 1):

You want to load the tinyMCE compressor version in this fashion, not the regular tiny_mce.js file.

Read here for more details: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Compressors

Basically the reason why it won't work as you have tried is because it needs to load certain javascript files in various orders.